# Save every page of a Word document into a txt file (utf-8) using vba

Tags: vba, utf-8, ms-word

I want to save every page of a Word Document as text File.
I do this with the following Code:

```
   Sub JedeSeiteEinNeuesDokumentOhneKopfUndFusszeilen()
  Dim oDoc As Document, nDoc As Document, oRange As Range
  Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
  Max = oDoc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
  For i = 1 To Max
    oDoc.Activate
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i
    Set oRange = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range
    If Right(oRange.Text, 1) = Chr(12) Then
      oRange.SetRange Start:=oRange.Start, End:=oRange.End - 1
    End If
    Set nDoc = Documents.Add(Template:=ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName)
    nDoc.Content.FormattedText = oRange.FormattedText
    s = nDoc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
    'Wenn eine 2. Seite mit einem einzigen leeren Absatz entstanden ist
    If s = 2 And nDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = Chr(13) Then
      nDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete
    End If
    nDoc.SaveAs FileFormat:=wdFormatUnicodeText, fileName:=Praefix & Format(i, "0"), AddToRecentFiles:=False
    nDoc.Close
  Next i
End Sub
```

But i want that the txt file is in utf-8. How do i do this?

Thanks
froyo
(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Answer for my question:

```
nDoc.SaveAs Encoding:=msoEncodingUTF8, FileFormat:=wdFormatUnicodeText, fileName:=Praefix & Format(i, "0"), AddToRecentFiles:=False
```

The solution was adding the part "Encoding:=msoEncodingUTF8" to the saveAs Method!

froyo